# getParameter method missing when I request

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to post data from a form and store it as a String using the getParameter and insert to database but it seems for me the getParameter is not even present. After request. I do not get that method. Tried rebuilding and no difference. Am I supposed to add external dependencies? I don't see any prompts for imports either.

My index.jsp file

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="img/logo.png">

    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameField" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordField" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <%  
        // .getParameter highlighted in red. Not valid
        String username = request.getParameter("usernameField");
        String password = request.getParameter("passwordField");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename", "root", "");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO stat(user, pass) VALUES (username, password)");

    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post error details? There's at least uncaught SQLException issues in your code. And bad SQL (not inserting anything)

Comment: @Jan I have commented out the sql portion. Trying to get .getParameter to work. There is no error on logs. The page opens on chrome. When i enter info into the fields and press the submit, no error either.

Comment: Code in a JSP is executed when the JSP is being rendered to be sent to the browser. Are the usernameField and passwordField values being provided in the URL for this JSP?

Comment: @Jason Not sure what you mean. The values are input by entering the information into the edit fields and clicking submit.

Comment: Yes, but the first time you request the page, the database code is being executed with no data from the form (since you haven't seen it yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your input tags should have a "name" attribute and this will be the name of the request parameter to get the value.
E.g.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameField" name="username" placeholder="Username">
```

and to retrieve it's value:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

If the above does not work here is a snippet to read all your request parameters and their values:

```
<%
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
  out.print("<b>" + paramName + ":</b>\n");
  String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
  out.println(paramValue);
}
%>
```

**EDIT** Ok a more complete example close to yours:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="img/logo.png">

    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameField" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordField" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <%  
        // .getParameter highlighted in red. Not valid
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<b>" + paramName + ":</b>\n");
            String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
            out.println(paramValue);
        }

    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cannot reslove method getParameterNames(). after request. , my only options are cast, field, par, try and var.

Comment: Cant really understand your comment, please see my revised answer, code is more close to yours

Comment: Trying to say having similar issues as before. getParameterNames and getHeader are not recognized. Those methods are highlighted in red. I am only able to call request.cast, request.field, request.par, request.try, request.var.

Comment: Ah ok, that's probably on your IDE. Which do you use? Eclipse? Have you tried running your code in a web server?

Comment: Using Intellij. Web server, using XAMPP and testing on localhost with tomcat server.

Comment: This so weird, it is highlighted as red, not recognised. but I logged the String value and able to derieve it correctly. So nothing I can do about it, purely IDE problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to add a `javax.servlet` dependency.

With Maven it's just the following:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```